# Question Regarding Getters & Setters

Tags: java, getter-setter

I know this might be a stupid question to many but I usually like to stick to correct/better implementation. In Java, when writing a getter/setter, would it be better to refer to the instance variable with `this` or access it directly?

Thanks

Comment: "local variable" != "instance variable".  Just for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not really matter as long as you refer to the proper variables.

Yet, it is a common practice to refer to the local fields with `this` so that you do not mix them up with local variables:

```
public void setField(int field)[
    this.field = field;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When writing a setter you are typically forced to refer to the **instance variable** (**not** the local variable) using `this` in order to differentiate between the instance variable and the parameter; e.g.

```
public void setFoo(int foo) {
  this.foo = foo;
}
```

However, when writing a getter method there is typically no need to prefix the instance variable with this:

```
public int getFoo() {
  return foo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is simply a matter of *taste*, although it has some particular use cases.

When **subclassing**, `this` keyword can be used for routines and variables to stress that they actually belong to super class (or this class) and not e.g., statically imported.

It's also commonly used to **disambiguate** parameters from local variables. E.g.,

```
private Foo foo;
public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
     this.foo = foo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `this` tends to alleviate any variable scope problems you might encounter later on.

It's not necessary, though.